# C# byte[][] SHA1

Tags: c#, byte, sha1

I have this code in C# that uses IKVM to utilize Java's SHA1 encryption.

```
    public static string ComputeHash(params byte[][] bytes)
    {
        if (bytes == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("bytes");
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        foreach (var item in bytes)
        {
            if (item == null)
                if (bytes == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("bytes", "Inner array is null");
            digest.update(item);
        }
        string s = (new java.math.BigInteger(digest.digest())).toString(16);
        return s;
    }
```

Is there an alternative rather than using IKVM for this?

Comment: A bit of a nitpick: SHA-1 is a cryptographic hash function, and not encryption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you could use the [Sha1CryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha1cryptoserviceprovider.aspx) class in System.Security.Cryptography.

Here's the code example from that page:

```
byte[] data = new byte[DATA_SIZE];

byte[] result; 

SHA1 sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider(); 
    // This is one implementation of the abstract class SHA1.

result = sha.ComputeHash(data);
```

I would not expect it to be too hard to change that example into one that takes jagged arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll look into this a more.